# printing a 2 pages of jframe in java

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe

i would like to print a jframe that contain a lot of textfield and buttons that contain a data. i want to print this jframe by clicking a Print jbutton. i tried this code.

```
protected void print() {
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
if(job.printDialog()){
  try {
    job.setPrintable(new Printable() {

      @Override
      public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
        if(pageIndex == 0){
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)graphics;
          g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

        Dimension dim = ODietListJFrame.this.getSize();
        double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
        double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

        // get the bounds of the printable area
        double pHeight = pageFormat.getImageableHeight();
        double pWidth = pageFormat.getImageableWidth();

        double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
        double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;

        g2d.scale(xRatio, yRatio);

          ODietListJFrame.this.printAll(g2d);
          return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
      }
    });
    job.print();
  } catch (PrinterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} else {
  System.err.println("Error printing");
}
```

}

My problem is that my jframe is too large that is must be print in two pages and this code print the second page. i want to print the first part from the jframe.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Well to start with, your `if (pageIndex == 0)` isn't going to help.  You need to ascertain the last y position that was print and print from the amount of the page height or the remain frame which ever is smaller

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that in coding, how to get y (the last position that  have been printed)?

Comment: Create a variable (probably called something like "y"), on integration, calculate the height of the area you are printing for this page, increment y by this amount until you run of of frame to print...

Comment: Can you tell me how by code example?

Comment: The jframe contain a scrollpane, so i want to print the part that doesn't appear in the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the first thing we need to is make sure that the component been printed is at it's preferred size...

```
component.setSize(component.getPreferredSize());
```

This is important, but also remember, that this will affect the component that is on the screen...

Next, we need to work out if we are printing a new page or re-printing the current page.  This occurs because `print` might be called multiple times for a given page...

```
if (lastPage != pageIndex) {
    lastPage = pageIndex;
    //...
}
```

We then need to calculate the y offset of the component that fits the current page...

```
yOffset = height * pageIndex;
if (yOffset > component.getHeight()) {
    yOffset = -1;
}
```

If the `yOffset` is greater then the `component` height, then we don't want to print any more pages.

Next, we print the page, to do this, we need to translate the `Graphics` context so that the `yOffset` becomes the new `0` position...

```
g2d.translate(0, -yOffset);
```

Then we print the component...

```
component.printAll(g2d);
```

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterResolution;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class PrintMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PrintMe();
    }

    public PrintMe() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane testPane = new TestPane();

                JButton btn = new JButton("Print");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                        aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
                        aset.add(new PrinterResolution(300, 300, PrinterResolution.DPI));

                        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                        pj.setPrintable(new MultiPagePrintable(testPane));

                        if (pj.printDialog(aset)) {
                            try {
                                pj.print(aset);
                                testPane.getParent().invalidate();
                                testPane.getParent().validate();
                            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(testPane));
                frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("Get your own image"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public class MultiPagePrintable implements Printable {

        private JComponent component;
        private int lastPage = 0;
        private double yOffset;

        public MultiPagePrintable(JComponent component) {
            this.component = component;
        }

        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            int result = NO_SUCH_PAGE;

            double height = pageFormat.getImageableHeight();
            component.setSize(component.getPreferredSize());

            if (lastPage != pageIndex) {
                lastPage = pageIndex;
                yOffset = height * pageIndex;
                if (yOffset > component.getHeight()) {
                    yOffset = -1;
                }
            }

            if (yOffset >= 0) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

                g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(),
                                (int) pageFormat.getImageableY());

                g2d.translate(0, -yOffset);
                component.printAll(g2d);
                result = PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

Now, this example only prints in the vertical direction, if you need it to print the horizontal direction as well, it gets a little more complicated, but that the basic concept remains the same

Comment: I have been tried yours, but it print a blank paper

Comment: I will be grateful if you help me, i have spend a week to solve it.

Comment: The code works with me also, Thanks. But i am sorry for that i take some of it inside my code because my frame is already exist, so it print ablank paper. My quetion is, in this line img = ImageIO.read(new File("Get your own image")); i should replace "Get your own image" with what? and very thanks for your help.

Comment: The example I have simply uses a large image to be displayed in the panel, which makes it scrollable.  Its only for demonstration purpose.  You should pass the component which is contained within the `JScrollPane` to the `MultiPagePrintable` class.  If you really want to test my code, you can just use an absolute path to any image you might have which is larger then a single page...

Comment: Thanks for fast replay, i will make my efforts and if i need thing i will ask you. Again very thanks for your help. Can you look to this question (the same question but it clarify more  what i want) http://stackoverflow.com/q/29120786/4502498