# swing- printing array of JFrames-only print first index

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have been trying to print array of JFrames in swing. Below code to handle print function which receive input as array of JFrames. It works only for first index and other index are printed as a blank. I tested using xps doc format. would you please  find out why the others index of array not printed

```
if (mainframe != null) {
    frameArray[looping]=mainframe;

    frameArray[looping].setName("FileName"+ (looping));
}

mainframe.setVisible(false);
if(looping==noOfPages-1)
printPages();
```

---

```
public void printPages() {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    boolean ok = job.printDialog();
    if(ok){
        try {
            for (int i=0;i< noOfPages;vch++){

                frameArray[i].setSize(210, 330);
                frameArray[i].getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
                frameArray[i].setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frameArray[i].setVisible(true);
                setPrintFrameArray(frameArray[i]);
                job.setPrintable(this);
                job.print();
                getPrintMassFrame().setVisible(true);
                getPrintMassFrame().removeAll();
                revalidate();
                getPrintMassFrame().repaint();
                frameArray[i].dispose();
            }
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

---

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)
        throws PrinterException {
    if (page > 0) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY() - 55);

    getPrintMassFrame().printAll(g);

    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

Comment: You only seem to be printing a single frame, getPrintMassFrame().printAll(g);. You're going to do a lot of calculates to determine if the frame occupies more then one page, and if the frame needs to printed over multiple pages, and keep doing this until you run out of frames, this will mean you won't want to return NO_SUCH_PAGE until you're actually done

Comment: Now having said that, I think you'd better at look into something like JasperReports

Comment: [For an example of printing a component over multiple pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000888/how-to-print-whole-jpanel-with-a-footer-in-every-page-in-java-swing/32001433#32001433)

Comment: I have only one page per frame. just need to print array of frames (single page per frame). Is there any way without JaserReports

Comment: Then, you could use the page index value to access each frame from the array