# How to print multiple JTables to a single page when space is available

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I have a java application with 2 JTable. The first table is made up of 2 columns and 5 rows always. The second JTable is made up of 4 columns and many columns.

I want to print JTable 1 above JTable 2, then continue to print the rest of JTable. How would I do this?

From a printable page perspective it would look as follows:

- Page 1: Has the first table plus as much of the second table that can fit on it.
- Page 2 to N: Has the rest of the second table.

I have an application that uses the Book Class to put together the 2 JTables and use a single print Job to print it. But each table starts on a new page. Which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Wait, when you say "print" usually that means printing to paper -- is this what you're talking about? If so, you would almost never print the component but rather would use a report generation utility library to print the data.

Comment: When I was looking at this years ago, JasperReports was the de facto open source standard, but that may have changed since then.

Comment: You would customise the printing process via your own printable, but trust me, this is a complete pain in the ... code ... better user something like Jasper Reports

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34114959#34114959) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34146067#34146067)

Comment: Remember, printing is hard, I'm mean it's really hard and complicated, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000888/how-to-print-whole-jpanel-with-a-footer-in-every-page-in-java-swing/32001433#32001433) and all this is doing is supporting multiple pages/overflow.  Printing a `JTable` manually would not be recommended

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments and a bit of research on my own it appears the best route is using Jasper Reports