# Can't get Graphics from the PrintJob object JAVA

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm trying to get the Graphic from the PrintJob object using getGraphic(), but I have a problem when that code running. The ClassCastException catch this `class sun.print.ProxyPrintGraphics cannot be cast to class java.awt.Graphics2D (sun.print.ProxyPrintGraphics and java.awt.Graphics2D are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')`.

And this is the code that I run:

```
try {
     Toolkit tkp = jPanel3.getToolkit();
     PrintJob pjp = tkp.getPrintJob(this, null, null);
     Graphics g = pjp.getGraphics();
     jPanel3.print(g);
     g.dispose();
     pjp.end();
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you want to print a component (or do any printing for that fact), then you need to make use of a `Printable` `interface`, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000888/how-to-print-whole-jpanel-with-a-footer-in-every-page-in-java-swing/32001433#32001433). Take a look at the [Printing Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer After I look at your example and the printing documentation finally I can understand now. I tried to use PrinterJob instead of PrintJob and implement Printable in my component and it works. Thanks for the answer.