# Java generate a pdf file from a jframe

Tags: java, swing, pdf

I'm creating a simple  invoice program, i have a frame in which user set the invoice, in your opinion what is the best way to generate a pdf file of the invoice.

This was my code but it doesn't work well because it not print the whole frame but just a piece of the frame.

```
public void PrintPdf(JPanel panel)throws IOException, DocumentException{
        com.itextpdf.text.Document doc=new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
        try{
            //PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Fattura.pdf"));
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Fattura.pdf"));
            doc.open();
            PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
            PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(500, 500);
            Graphics2D g2 = template.createGraphics(500, 500);
            panel.print(g2);
            g2.dispose();
            contentByte.addTemplate(template, 30, 800);
        //doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello this is a pdf file from project tabelle"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
        if(doc.isOpen()){
            doc.close();
            }
        }
```

Can anyone help me to fix the code or suggest other way?

Comment: Is your JFrame larger than 500x500?

Comment: The answer is, don't, seriously, unless you like lots and lots of pain, just don't.  I highly recommend something like Jasper Reports instead

Comment: If you really hate yourself, you could have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070689/printing-a-2-pages-of-jframe-in-java/29137211#29137211) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000888/how-to-print-whole-jpanel-with-a-footer-in-every-page-in-java-swing/32001433#32001433) which should give you some ideas. If, however, you don't want that kind of pain, you could have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086377/printing-a-jpanel-with-scrollable-jtable-on-it/34146067#34146067) instead

Comment: Long answer made short.  `paint` the component to `BufferedImage`, make sure the component has been relaid out to the width you want to print.  Split the image by the height of the page, adding each subimage to PDF until you've added the entire image; wonder why elements are split across two pages

Comment: Painting to an image results in bad quality pdfs. Better create the pdf version of the invoice using the pdf library directly. I.e. not at all directly from frame or panel.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Will Jasper Reports produce textual output? Because a bill should absolutely not be an image.

Comment: @AndrewThompson That depends on the destination, but "generally" yes, it can output directly to PDF, Word, Excel or the Printer (as well as an image)

Comment: @JoeC yes is larger, but is there a way to resize the frame while i print on the pdf?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah i know it's not easy, but i have to do this for a project i need to consign next week. Thanks for example i will take a look